# Cual es la forma correcta de insertar informacion de un array de objetos dentro de un contenedor HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

soy nuevo dentro de esto de la programación web, he visto ya algunos cursos y conozco algo de HTML, CSS y JS, ultimamente me he tomado tiempo para practicar y he decidido crear una pagina donde consumo una API publica e inserto algunas propiedades dentro de tarjetas de informacion en un contenedor HTML.

Cree un algoritmo que funciona bastante bien el cual crea **rows** y **columns** dentro de un contenedor y les asigna una id diferente a cada **column** que es el que utilizo para agregar las **tarjetas** con información, debo decir que para estas estructuras utilizo **Bootstrap**, en fin este algoritmo funciona pero algo me dice que no es la manera, cual seria otra manera mas eficiente de hacerlo?

```js
"use strict";
// Funcion que retorna el JSON con informacion de los personajes
async function getChars() {
  let response = await fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters");
  let chars = response.json();
  return chars;
}
// Declaracion de variables
let content = document.getElementById("content");
let personajes;
let fotoPersonajes;
let nombresPersonajes;

// Funcion que crea las Rows con 4 columnas dependiendo de el numero de tarjetas a renderizar.
function createRow(items) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items; i += 4) {
    content.innerHTML += `<div class="row mb-3"><div class="col" id="c${i}"></div><div class="col"id="c${
      i + 1
    }"></div><div class="col"id="c${i + 2}"></div><div class="col"id="c${
      i + 3
    }"></div></div>`;
  }
}

// Codigo a ejecutar cuando la promesa termine.
getChars().then((chars) => {
  personajes = chars;

  // Creando array con la propiedad nombre de cada personaje.
  nombresPersonajes = personajes.map((elem) => {
    return elem.name;
  });
  // Creando array de la propiedad image url de cada personaje
  fotoPersonajes = personajes.map((elem) => {
    return elem.img;
  });
  // Creando las rows y columns para empezar a insertar las tarjetas en el HTML
  createRow(personajes.length);
  // Ciclo que crea las tarjetas con la foto y el nombre de cada personaje
  for (let i = 0; i < personajes.length; i++) {
    let id = "c" + i;
    let casilla = document.getElementById(id);
    casilla.innerHTML += `<div class="card  mx-auto" style="width: 18rem; max-width: 14rem;"><img src="${fotoPersonajes[i]}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title text-center">${nombresPersonajes[i]}</h5>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Seguramente hay otras formas, quizá algunas que utilicen menos código que otras, pero tené en cuenta que si funciona tal y cual vos esperas que lo haga, y el resultado es previsible, se puede decir que esta bien. si tenes ganas podemos buscar alternativas y plantearlas, pero lo que hiciste esta correcto. pd: Edite tu pregunta para que sea ejecutable.

Comment: @FacundoE.Villagra Tu respuesta me hizo plantearme mejor mi pregunta, entonces si mi codigo funciona y es legible para otros progrmadores podemos decir que es correcto, entonces por ej. si quiero crear un e-commerce y desplegar mis productos estaria bien hacerlo de esta manera verdad?, no hay algo como una manera general para hacer esto?

Comment: Efectivamente, siempre existirá otra forma, pero si funciona y cumple tus necesidades, es suficiente, por ejemplo, la respuesta que te planteo abajo no contempla el limite de 4 cards que agregaste, tené en cuenta que siempre se puede mejorar.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por resolver mis dudas y ayudarme a optimizar el codigo, un abrazo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá te dejo una versión mas simplificada, seguramente se puede seguir mejorando, saludos.

```js
fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters")
.then(response=> response.json())
.then((chars) => document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = chars.map( (personaje,index) =>
    `<div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-3" id="c${index}">
            <div class="card  mx-auto" style="width: 18rem; max-width: 14rem;">
                <img src="${personaje.img}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">${personaje.name}</h5>
                </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
).join(""))
```

```html
<div id="content"> </div>
```